# Check User Login Against AD Group

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, active-directory-group, directoryentry

I have a LDAP login setup in my C# web app that uses a DirectoryEntry method.  The below code is what I have so far.  This will let anybody with an AD account login.  I need to limit that to people in a group named "commonusers".

```
    public Boolean ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        string path = "LDAP://domain.company.org";
        DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path, userName, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        try
        {
            DirectorySearcher dirSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry);
            dirSearcher.FindOne();
            return true;
            // If it returns the data then the User is validated otherwise it will automatically shift to catch block and return false
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
```

The login button uses the code below:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            Boolean boolresult = ValidateUser(TextBox_username.Text, TextBox_password.Text);
            if (boolresult)
            {
                Label_loginstatus.Text = "Redirecting";

                Response.Redirect("medsearch.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Label_loginstatus.Text = "Invalid username/password! Please try again.";
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to add a function that checks the users account for the "commonusers" group into one of these functions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If on .NET 4 you could use this method, where you can do with out try/catch:

```
     private bool ValidateAgainstADAndGroup(string username, string password, string groupname)
                {
                    var ok = false;
                    using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.lan"))
                    {
                        if (pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password))
                        {
                            //User is alright
                            using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(pc)))
                            {
                                searcher.QueryFilter.SamAccountName = username;
                                Principal u = searcher.FindOne();
                                foreach (Principal p in u.GetGroups())
                                {
                                    if (p.Name == groupname)
                                    {
                                        //User is in group
                                        ok= true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return ok;
                }
```

You could alter to return two types of errors: NotAuthenticated  OR Authenticated - but not in group

Comment: Is there a reference that needs added to go this route?  I added this code and PrincipalContext, ContextType, PrincipalSearcher, UserPrincipal and Principal are all coming up as errors.

Comment: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement - Bedtime reading here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So this code worked filtering out users that are not in groups however it is allowing users who are in the designated group to login without a password...

Comment: Nvm, I added my directorysearcher/findone command into the code you provided above, thank you for your help!  I've been stumped on this since last week!

Comment: No problem - glad to help. But....you are saying that the validateCredentials is returning true with a blank password?

Comment: I'm testing this on my dev machine. ValidateCredentials returns true, but FindOne returns null!?

Comment: This worked for me.  I added one line of code though to break out of the foreach loop once the user is found.  Insert "break;" after the line "ok = true;".  I also added the check for a null value returned from the call to searcher.FindOne() suggested in Chris' post below.

Answer (score 0):

You want to capture the result of the FindOne() call to look for whatever property value you care about:

```
DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path, userName, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
object obj = de.NativeObject;  // This will force the authentication

// Search for the user's directory entry
DirectorySearcher dirSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry);
dirSearcher.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + userName + ")";
dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member");
SearchResult searchResult = dirSearcher.FindOne();

if (searchResult != null)
{
    if (searchResult.Properties["member"] != null && searchResult.Properties["member"].Contains("commonusers"))
    {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

For more info on how to get data out of Active Directory, I recommend visiting [www.selfadsi.org](http://www.selfadsi.org)

Comment: So I put that code in place and now it won't let members or non members through.  Do I need to change the code of my button click now?

Comment: Your button click event code should be fine. I would step through the ValidateUser code and confirm searchResult has a value, and then see what the value of searchResult.Properties["member"] actually is. Note that another property you can try to retrieve is MemberOf, which is basically a list of the groups the given account is a member of. Also note that Steen's answer is the newer way to do this type of thing, so if you are running .NET 4.0 or above it would probably be easier to go that route.

Comment: If I send the searchresult to a label this is what it returns:

LDAP://domain.company.org/CN=smith\, john,OU=Normal User Accounts,OU=Users,OU=TTH,OU=Central Region,DC=domain,DC=company,DC=org 

It feels like I'm sooo close but I just can't figure it out!

Comment: That looks like the data associated with that user's directory entry, such as what OU they are in, their common name, etc. Does serachResults.Properties["member"] have a value?